# Mac Terminal - Create animated gif from png files

Tags: terminal, png, gif

I have a bunch of png files named as 1.png, 2.png, etc. and I want to create an animated gif image from them all. I haven't been successful in finding a solution for a terminal command that will convert these png files into a single animated gif.

Can someone post some commands that I can try? I have tried "convert" commands but my terminal always says convert is not found even though I have installed ImageMagik.

Comment: If you are (fairly) sure `convert` should be somewhere in your system, try [`whereis`](http://superuser.com/questions/40301/which-whereis-differences).

Answer (score 51):

`convert *.png screens.gif`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23309196/517381) suggested installing `convert` with `brew install ImageMagick`.

Comment: You can run this from the `Finder` context menu with `Automator`: https://jacobsalmela.com/2015/11/02/make-animated-gifs-in-os-x-with-a-right-click/

Comment: This won't take the ordering of your frames.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!, I did not know I could convert files so easy

Answer (score 35):

ImageMagick's `convert` command works perfectly for this but you'll want to list the filenames in the correct order. Using `*.png` will jumble frames if the digits don't have the leading zeros because the ordering is alphabetical:

```
1.png  10.png  11.png  2.png  3.png  ...
```

If you use zsh you can simply use a glob qualifier:

```
convert *.png(n) out.gif
```

Otherwise you can sort the ls output

```
convert $(ls *.png | sort -V) out.gif
```

If your filenames have leading zeros go ahead and use `*.png`. Note that the default delay between frames is small, so depending on your use case the frame rate might be too quick. To change that use the `-delay` option, for example:

```
convert -delay 50 *.png out.gif
```

This will set FPS to 100/50 = 2 frames per second.