# How to make GIF from Android device screen

Tags: android, screenshot, gif

I can capture Android device screen:

`adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > adb-screenshot-$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).png`

How can I squash all those images into single GIF?

Comment: How does this relate to Android programming?

Comment: When you create new app and want to showcase it, you'll probably do it much better with GIF. :)

Comment: **1** But I only see efforts to do things outside the programming environment. **2** PNGs really have a BETTER QUALITY (But this isn't your goal, since you want an animated gif).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) command of ImageMagick to combine your .png files into one .gif animation :

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 *.png anim.gif
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I found it.

First done screenshots in single folder and then converted it all to GIF like this:

`convert *.png screens.gif`

Installed ***ImageMagick*** as [described here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx).

On Mac OS X, I've installed it like this: `brew install ImageMagick`.

Comment: is there anyway to control the period on each frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can use my fully working script here: [android-screen-gif.sh](https://gist.github.com/sveinungkb/3a5753da908489fc0c26).
You simply run it with `./android-screen-gif.sh`, let it record and hit `Ctrl + C` when you want to stop. 
The images will be pulled and a GIF assembled, very useful for demos/issue tracker/email!
Requires `convert` to be on path, see the other posts here about ImageMagick.

```
Wrote screenshot to /sdcard/Screenshot-20150707-105440/Screenshot-20150707-105440-1.png
Wrote screenshot to /sdcard/Screenshot-20150707-105440/Screenshot-20150707-105440-2.png
Wrote screenshot to /sdcard/Screenshot-20150707-105440/Screenshot-20150707-105440-3.png
Wrote screenshot to /sdcard/Screenshot-20150707-105440/Screenshot-20150707-105440-4.png
Wrote screenshot to /sdcard/Screenshot-20150707-105440/Screenshot-20150707-105440-5.png
Downloading images.
pull: building file list...
pull: /sdcard/Screenshot-20150707-105440/Screenshot-20150707-105440-5.png -> ./Screenshot-20150707-105440-5.png
pull: /sdcard/Screenshot-20150707-105440/Screenshot-20150707-105440-4.png -> ./Screenshot-20150707-105440-4.png
pull: /sdcard/Screenshot-20150707-105440/Screenshot-20150707-105440-3.png -> ./Screenshot-20150707-105440-3.png
pull: /sdcard/Screenshot-20150707-105440/Screenshot-20150707-105440-2.png -> ./Screenshot-20150707-105440-2.png
pull: /sdcard/Screenshot-20150707-105440/Screenshot-20150707-105440-1.png -> ./Screenshot-20150707-105440-1.png
5 files pulled. 0 files skipped.
6077 KB/s (5015743 bytes in 0.805s)
Assembled gif Screenshot-20150707-105440.gif
Cleaned up individual screenshots.
```